# HTML replace iFrame with an "input"

Tags: iframe, input

Within my webserver, I have an iframe which read a text file to show a number on the webpage.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ST84R.png)

But I would like to remove the iframe and show this number within an "input" field.
I tried various tests, but nothing works.

The code for the iframe:

```
<iframe id='iframe' align="left" src = '/var/www/bat' onload='readfile()'width="50" height="25" name="iframe"></iframe>
```

So, is it possible to move the iframe with something like this :

```
<input size="1" type="text" name="number" id="numberId"></input>
```

Thanks for your help and support.

Best regards,

Comment: Let's try to understand better...maybe this could be the main idea: you have to inspect the DOM, extract the html code of the frame, pickup just the number and put it inside your input tag in JS with `document.getElementById('numberId').value=extractedValue;`

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will give a try to see how it works and get back to you if I have some issues. Thanks one more time.